# dynamic content overlap footer but remain within content flow?

Tags: html, css

My footer if quite high so I'm wondering if it is possible to get the content to overlap it slightly whilst still remaining in the content flow?

I suppose the alternative is to make the footer a few thousand pixels high and position it at the bottom. It's not an elegant solution though, anyone have a better idea?

[http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/temporary-images/footer-overlap.jpg http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/temporary-images/footer-overlap.jpg](http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/temporary-images/footer-overlap.jpg)

Comment: thanks Ken, I aspire to be a napkin note king one day and thanks to you am one step closer ;)

Comment: agree with first comment. +1 for napkin notes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems a nice idea. If you need overlapping, then some absolute position must be done.

Set your footer absolutely to the bottom of the page and z-index:0. Then your content z-index:1 and padding-bottom: (footer height - desired overlap).

Comment: Thanks Seb, that sounds like a good solution to me. I'll try it, many thanks indeed :)

Comment: Hi Seb, I got it working :) http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/smokinhot/templates/smokinhot/

Although I've added a left column just to make things a little harder but I can't seem to get to be in the content flow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) which I found a while ago [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

I made this which works in Firefox, but I can't get it to play nice with IE 7.  Anybody's help would be awesome.

**EDIT:  Made it work**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>A CSS Sticky Footer with Overlap</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 700px;
}
.header {
    /*Go download the header yourself from http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/header.png
    Please don't steal the guy's bandwidth*/
    background: transparent url(header.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 160px;
}
.footer_bg {
    /*Go download the header yourself from http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/footer.jpg
    Please don't steal the guy's bandwidth*/
    background: transparent url(footer.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 700px;
}

.footer {
    clear:both;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer_bg p {
    bottom: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.push {
    height: 142px;
    position: absolute;
}
.footer {
    height: 142px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#content {
    z-index: 10;
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>CSS Sticky Footer</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>A CSS sticky footer that just works</h2>
        <p>We've all tried to use a <strong>sticky footer</strong> one time or another, but they never seem to come out right, do they? Well, the days of a hard to understand CSS-based <strong>sticky footer</strong> are thankfully over. In just a few simple CSS classes with minimal extra HTML markup, I've fashioned a <strong>sticky footer</strong> that even beginners can get a handle on. It's been tested in IE 5 and up, Firefox, Safari and Opera.</p>
        <h2>Usage of the CSS</h2>
        <p><q>Great! this is exactly what I'm looking for! Can I use it?</q></p>
        <p>Absolutely. There are no terms, licenses, fees or requirements. Use it as you will. If you find the kindness to link to me on your site, I'd appreciate it, but it's by no means necessary. Have fun, and don't be afraid to ask me any questions or send me your thoughts.</p>
        <p class="download"><a href="layout.css" title="Download the stylesheet">View the CSS</a> or <a href="/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/" title="Make a footer stick to the bottom of a page">learn about using it</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_bg">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2006-2008 <a href="http://ryanfait.com/" title="Las Vegas Web Design">Ryan Fait</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for but a great resource :)

Comment: I know.  I am trying right now to use it to do the overlap, which is a nice look by the way.  I really like the idea.